# PHP - Is this the factory method pattern?

Tags: oop, design-patterns

I saw a resource online
http://www.labelmedia.co.uk/blog/posts/design-patterns-factory-method.html

From what I know this is not really the pattern. It's more of a mix between the the Simple Factory Idiom and Simple Factory Method.

Did they get it wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, yes. It looks more like a Simple Factory indeed. However, it might be they are refering to what is sometimes called ["Static Factory Method"](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=static+factory+method).